# Java Simple Program having some error

Tags: java

```
class HelloWorld {

    static int num1 = 12;
    static int num2 = 56;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int sum;
        int sub;
        int prd;
        int div;

        sum = num1+num2;
        sub = num1-num2;
        prd = num1*num2;
        div = num1/num2;

        output(sum);
        output(sub);
        output(prd);
        output(div);
    }

    public static void output(int input);
    {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

I am having the following error: dont know what does it mean ? Kindly anyone tell me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:6)
```

Comment: what is the code at line 6 ?

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine, but it doesn't tell us what is at line 6 that the compiler might find a problem with

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;`

```
public static void output(int input);< here
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the method signature

```
public static void output(int input) // -- no semi colon at the end here
{
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just remove the semi colon

```
public static void output(int input); <<<< here
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have added semicolon at method definition

```
class HelloWorld 
{

        static int num1 = 12;
        static int num2 = 56;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            int sum;
            int sub;
            int prd;
            int div;

            sum = num1+num2;
            sub = num1-num2;
            prd = num1*num2;
            div = num1/num2;

            output(sum);
            output(sub);
            output(prd);
            output(div);
        }

        public static void output(int input)
        {
            System.out.println(input);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the same one I have made so often. You have made a very simple syntax error by having a semicolon at the end of your output method's declaration. Take that semicolon out and the code will work.